# How to make a responsive bootstrap table inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make a span display inline with a bootstrap responsive table? Currently the span displays on a new line. I'd like the span to be to the right of the table, vertically centered with the table header.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Sibling(s)</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Birthdate</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" name="sibling-gender1" id="sibling-gender1">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>M</option>
                            <option>F</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" name="sibiling-name1" id="sibiling-name1" style="width: 100%;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" name="sibling-birthdate1" id="sibling-birthdate1" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY"
                               style="width: 100%;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" name="sibling-school1" id="sibling-school1" style="width: 100%;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" name="sibling-grade1" id="sibling-grade1">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                            <option>7</option>
                            <option>8</option>
                            <option>9</option>
                            <option>10</option>
                            <option>11</option>
                            <option>12</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        <!-- end .form-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .panel-body -->
</div>
<!-- end .panel -->
```

Comment: To the right of the table, vertically centered with the table header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the display property of the `.table-responsive`/`span` elements to `table-cell`. Just give `.table-responsive` a width of `100%` in order to fill the remaining space. Additionally, you might also need to add padding to the span element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/avVxr/)

```
.table-responsive {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
.table-responsive + .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus {
    display:table-cell;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

If you want the span element to be aligned in the middle, all you would have to do is add `vertical-align:middle` to the element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3R6zJ/)

```
.table-responsive + .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus {
    display:table-cell;
    padding-left:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

It's worth noting that this CSS assumes that the element are adjacent siblings. If they aren't, you would need to change the selectors.

Comment: Thanks! This works well, but is there a way to align it with the table header so that the span is displayed in the vertical center of the table header?

Comment: The vertical-align example aligns it to the entire table.

Comment: @NathanJones Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nm2V.jpg)? Or like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xMhZG.jpg).. or are you talking about the "Siblings.." text?

Comment: Like the first one, but the span looks like it should be a bit higher to be in the vertical center according to the header position. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @NathanJones Wouldn't `vertical-align:top` work then? http://jsfiddle.net/A9Rfs/ .. you could always add a `padding-top` value... http://jsfiddle.net/k9f6p/

Answer (score 0):

A Bootstrap way could be to make the `.panel-body` a `.row` too and its children (`.table-responsive, .glyphicon`) become columns:

```
<div class="panel-body row">
    <div class="col-xs-11 table-responsive "></div>
    <span class="col-xs-1 glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
```

The vertical center of the table header cannot be determined through CSS (as it is just one part of the left columns height), but you can adjust the top-paddings of the table header cells and the icon.